# Dividing a 2D plane into areas that belong together

Tags: computational-geometry

I have multiple polygons where some are of different color and some of equal color. I want to group them into areas (e.g. new polygons) that completely contain all polygons of the same color.

See the two simple examples which would both satisfy these conditions. The dotted red lines are the desired result.

[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]

The first example divides the whole plane, the second does not. I don't care as long as all polygons of same color are grouped.

It can be assumed that a solution exists, i.e. there will not be a polygon of blue color fully enclosed by one of black color. Also polygons do not intersect but may share a border like in the example. However, edge cases like this could occur:

[image: Exception]

I'm looking for an algorithm that can accomplish this. The first example reminded my of Voronoi diagrams, but it's different because I have polygons not individual points.

A real world example of this would be to divide a city into districts base on housing blocks.

Comment: Hint: take a point in every black polygon and link them by means of a path planning algorithm that avoids all non-black polygons. Repeat with the other colors, keeping the previously established connections.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is to apply these steps iteratively:

1. Use a buffer algorithm to grow all polygons.
2. Combine the ones of equal color with a union operation.
3. Iterate all resulting shapes and substract all other shapes from them, in order to get rid of overlapping areas. This iteration must be done alternatingly from the start and the end, otherwise the shapes will grow unevenly.

These steps are repeated until the result looks visually pleasing. This procedure does not handle the special case mentioned in the second picture of the question (it will isolate the two blue polygons), but it was in the end an acceptable compromise for my use case.